# Sl4j logger does not log when it used in conjunction with ResponseEntityExceptionHandler for catching exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, lombok

I have used `@ControllerAdvice` to create a catch-all exception handler to catch all exceptions and log accordingly. However, for some reason, the sl4j logger fails to log to console. The same logger works every other place in my application but it does not work in the catch-all exception handler.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class CatchAllExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> catchAllExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    ApiError apiError =
        ApiError.builder()
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .message("An internal service issue")
            .debugMessage(ex.getMessage())
            .build();
    log.debug("An issue has occurred, {}, {}", kv("message", ex.getMessage()),
        kv("trace", ex.getStackTrace()));
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
  }
}
```

`Sl4j` from Lombok has been used but I am not sure if this has anything to do with Lombok. I can see that the superclass (`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`) has its own `logger` so I don't think any weird variable hiding is happening, but I am not sure.

I am pretty sure my logging profile and configuration is correct as it's working any other places except inside this catch-all exception handler. It just simply does not print anything in logs.

UPDATE:

I can use logger from the superclass and it works. However, it uses apache commons-logging which is missing some specific methods I need here.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot default log level is `info` so `debug` logs are getting suppressed. I slightly modified your code to reproduce the issue.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> catchAllExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
  log.info("******");
  log.debug("An issue has occurred, {}", ex.getMessage());
  log.info("An issue has occurred, {}", ex.getMessage());
  log.info("******");
  return ResponseEntity.status(500).build();
}
```

**Output from above code:**
See only info logs got printed.

```
2020-09-03 22:25:45.065  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : ******
2020-09-03 22:25:45.065  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : An issue has occurred, test exception
2020-09-03 22:25:45.065  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : ******
```

**Solution 1:**
Change `log.debug` to `log.info` or `log.warn` or `log.error`. This suites more in your case.

**Solution 2:**
Add a property to enable debug log for `CatchAllExceptionHandler` in your `application.properties`.

```
logging.level.com.example.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler=debug
```

**Output after adding above property:**

```
2020-09-03 22:36:05.389  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : ******
2020-09-03 22:36:05.389 DEBUG c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : An issue has occurred, test exception
2020-09-03 22:36:05.389  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : An issue has occurred, test exception
2020-09-03 22:36:05.389  INFO c.e.demo.main.CatchAllExceptionHandler   : ******
```

Comment: The log leve has been set for ALL already so there is no issue related to the log level and the same approach works without any issues in other classes of the same project, so I don't think it's about the log level or the log profile.

Comment: Can you add your exception handler code in a try catch. It may be that control is not reaching to the log.debug line

Comment: It's already been shared in the question. It reaches to that line and successfully runs that line (I've checked it in the debug mode). There is a logger variable from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler that I can use instead of Sl4j here and it works without any issues. Sl4j works everywhere else in my application except here. I suspect there is some sort of conflict between sl4j logger and Apache common logging logger (as per the superclass) that is causing this issue.